# VHDL: How do I delay VGA signals?

Tags: vhdl, delay, vga

I am using a Basys3 FPGA and I have a test pattern generator which displays a set of images on the monitor. The problem is, that every image is 'glitched', meaning that the first pixel in every horizontal line is the pixel from the previous line. For example, if I had a black&white screen, with the upper half white, and the lower half black, the first pixel in the first black line would be white. Basically, it looks like the whole first vertical column is shifted downwards with one pixel.

From what I've been told by my professor, the problem is caused by the fact that the signals (h_sync, v_sync, RGB) are not synchronized, h_sync and v_sync being ahead with 1 bit, due to the delay of the RGB signals when I make the selection of the images. By selection I mean, that I have 4 active switches that (based on their ON/OFF state) select the images in a 'binary way'. (example: the 4 switches are in 0101 state, then the 5th image is displayed. 0011 state, 3rd image displayed and so on.)

This is the code for the selection:

```
type Colors is array (0 to 15) of STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
signal redArr   : Colors;
signal greenArr : Colors;
signal blueArr  : Colors;

process (CLK)
begin
if (CLK'EVENT and CLK = '1') then
    if flagAV = '1' then
        RED <= redArr (conv_integer (SW));
        GREEN <= greenArr (conv_integer (SW));
        BLUE <= blueArr (conv_integer (SW));
    else
        RED <= "00000000";
        GREEN <= "00000000";
        BLUE <= "00000000";
    end if;
LED <= SW;
end if;
end process;
```

The array (Colors) has 16 elements because I have 16 images, thus 4 switches (SW) are enough to display all of them. I used 8 bits per color. The `flagAV` is just to check whether I am the active region or not.

I have a separate module (VGADraw) for this selection of images, and another one (VGADrive) where i define the H/V sync, H/V blank signals.  The counters are then built in the image selection module using the H/V blank signals from VGADrive.

The H/V sync and blank signals defined in VGADrive:

```
HorizontalSync: process (CLK)
begin
if (CLK'EVENT and CLK = '1') then
    if (inCntHor = RES.cstHorFP + RES.cstHorAL - 1) then
        inHS <= '0';
    elsif (inCntHor = RES.cstHorFP + RES.cstHorAL + RES.cstHorPW - 1) then
        inHS <= '1';
    end if;
end if;
end process;

HorizontalBlanking: process (CLK)
begin
if (CLK'EVENT and CLK = '1') then
    if (inCntHor = RES.cstHorAL - 1) then
        inHBL <= '1';
    elsif (inCntHor = RES.cstHorTotSize - 1) then
        inHBL <= '0';
    end if;
end if;
end process;

VerticalSync: process (CLK)
begin
if (CLK'EVENT and CLK = '1') then
    if (inCntVer = RES.cstVerFP + RES.cstVerAL - 1) then
        inVS <= '0';
    elsif (inCntVer < RES.cstVerFP + RES.cstVerAL + RES.cstVerPW - 1) then
        inVS <= '1';
    end if;       
end if;
end process;

VerticalBlanking: process (CLK)
begin
if (CLK'EVENT and CLK = '1') then
    if (inCntVer = RES.cstVerAL - 1) then
        inVBL <= '1';
    elsif (inCntVer = RES.cstVerTotSize - 1) then
        inVBL <= '0';
    end if;
end if;
end process;
```

Counters built in the image selection module (VGADraw) using blanking signals:

```
VerticalCounter: process (CLK)
begin
if (CLK'EVENT and CLK = '1') then
    HBLold <= HBL;
    if HBL = '0' and HBLold = '1' then
        if VBL = '1' then
            incntVer <= 0;
        else
            incntVer <= incntVer + 1;
        end if;          
    end if;        
end if;
end process;

HorizontalCounter: process (CLK)
begin
if (CLK'EVENT and CLK = '1') then
    if HBL = '1' then
        incntHor <= 0;
    else
        incntHor <= incntHor + 1;
    end if;
end if;
end process;
```

cstHorAL - pixels / active lines

cstHorFP - pixels / front porch

cstHorPW - pixels / pulse width

cstHorBP - pixels / back porch

cstHorTotSize - pixels / total lines

cstVerAL - lines / active lines

cstVerFP - lines / front porch

cstVerPW - lines / pulse width

cstVerBP - lines / back porch

cstVerTotSize - lines / total frames

HBLold - used for falling edge detection

My question is, how do I delay the h_sync and v_sync signals by that 1 bit, so the images are displayed correctly without those first pixels being shifted, and in which module do I do it?

Comment: You are asking a question about signals that don't appear in the posted code. So you can only expect a vague answer; which will be : just assign them in a clocked process like the above. (Oh and use the `rising_edge` function instead of messing about with low level event attributes).

Comment: The truth is, I did not know which part of the code to post, the full code would be too much. But I'll add the sequences where I'm defining the sync, blank and counter signals.

Comment: I think I implemented it how you said, and the 'distortion' seems to have gotten smaller. But there still is a thin column glitching. Anything else I could do? I tried delaying it some more with  `after` statement, but no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you implemented one cycle delay, try more cycle delays such as:

```
process(CLK) is
begin
  if rising_edge(CLK) then
    a_q <= a;
    a_q_q <= a_q;
    a_q_q_q <= a_q_q;
    -- etc
  end if;
end process;
```

If you want cleaner code you can use a FOR loop to delay any signal as many cycles as you want such as

```
-- In Architecture
constant num_cycles : INTEGER := 3;
signal   a_v : std_logic_vector(num_cycles downto 0);

begin
  a_v(0) <= a;
  process(CLK) is
  begin
    if rising_edge(CLK) then
      for i in 0 to num_cycles loop
        a_v(i+1) <= a_v(i);
      end loop;
    end if;
  end process;
end architecture;
```

In this case a can be h_sync or v_sync. num_cycles is the number of cycles you want to delay. a_v is a vector. To use you delayed signal just use a_v(num_cycles)

Comment: Or you can do it in less code.  Instead of the `a_v(0) <= a`,  eliminate the for loop and do `a_v <= a_v(num_cycles-1 downto 0) & a;`.

Comment: So from what I understand, i put `a_v <= a_v(num_cycles-1 downto 0) & a`  inside the if clause, eliminating the for loop?

Comment: And where will I have my delayed signal? Still in a? Or will it be in  a_v(num_cycles)?

Comment: No. It'll be in a_v(num_cycles)

Comment: Ok, I will try it out. Thank you both very much for your help!